# What does this `^` operator mean in Dart?

Tags: dart

What does this `^` operator mean in Dart?

```
int get hashCode => cityName.hashCode ^ temperatureCelsius.hashCode;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the ^ (XOR) operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526584/what-does-the-xor-operator-do)

Comment: @ArthurAttout - That's for Python... May not be the same in Dart.

Comment: I can assure you it's the same in Dart :-).

Comment: Doc: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#operators

Comment: @ArthurAttout - you're right, but it would be better to post a comment that points to a Dart post than a Python ...

Comment: [Okay then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146809/what-does-caret-sign-do-in-dart)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does Caret sign do in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146809/what-does-caret-sign-do-in-dart)

Comment: Also, please review the *entire* language tour before coding more in Dart.  That should have been your first step, but some people immediately dive in to necessarily incomplete video courses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` operator is a user-defined binary operator. A class can define it to mean whatever it wants.
Some built-in Dart classes have a `^` operator, namely `int` and `bool`.

For `bool`, the `^` operator is the exclusive-or operation, the result is true if and only iff exactly one of the operands are `true` (and the other is then `false` because it must be a `bool`).

For `int`, the `^` operator is the bitwise exclusive or operation. The integer numbers are interpreted as the bits of their two's complement representation, and the bits of the two operands at the same position are exclusive-or'ed so the result is 1 if and only if exactly one of the two bits is 1.
Example:

```dart
  var x = 27;    // bits: ..0011011
  var y = 37;    // bits: ..0100101
  var z = x ^ y; // bits: ..0111110 - aka 62
```

Non-platform classes can also implement the operator, like in [the fixnum package](https://github.com/dart-lang/fixnum/blob/master/lib/src/int32.dart#L219).

Answer (score 0):

In many languages, including Dart, the `^` operator stands for a bitwise XOR operation.

What this does, conceptually, is to turn both of its operands into bit-strings of equal length and apply the exclusive-or logic to every pair of bits.

Example:

Let's say our inputs are the number 7 and the number 14. Here are their binary (bit-string) representations:

```
 7: 0111
14: 1110
```

In that case the result will be:

```
 9: 1001
```

In your example this seems to be used for creating a hash from two other hash values. That's the "default" way of combining two hash values, the reason being explained here:

[Why is XOR the default way to combine hashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889238/why-is-xor-the-default-way-to-combine-hashes)